# How to shorten this line of code?

Tags: php

i want to ask, how can i shorten this code?

I've tried with ifelse but i dont get it..

I have this

```
if (empty($data['current_password'])) {
        return false;
    }


    if (empty($data['new_password'])) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($data['new_password'] !== $data['new_password_again']) {
        return false;
    }
```

Tried

```
if () {
} elseif (empty($data['current_password'])) {
} elseif ($data['new_password'] !== $data['new_password_again']) {
}
```

But doesnt work, please help

thank you very much

Comment: Unless you have like 20+ of those checks, what you have is pretty standard. After that you can start getting into things like `foreach($data as $field => $value){ if(empty($value)){ return false; } }` or something.

Comment: You really must learn boolean operators like OR.

Comment: you can use OR. for example `if (empty($a) || empty($b) || ($c !== $d)) {
    return false;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
if (empty($data['current_password']) || empty($data['new_password']) || $data['new_password'] !== $data['new_password_again']) 
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like magical things, try this

```
switch (true) {
    case (empty($data['current_password'])):
    case (empty($data['new_password'])):
    case ($data['new_password'] !== $data['new_password_again']):
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ?

```
return (empty($data['current_password']) || empty($data['new_password']) || $data['new_password'] !== $data['new_password_again']) ? false : '';
```

Comment: in case none of the condition match, user is not retuning anything but u r returning a blank string

Comment: He asking shortening, return value for none of condition matched its his responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

try below one,

```
return(empty($data['current_password'])||empty($data['new_password'])||$data['new_password'] !== $data['new_password_again']?FALSE:'');
```